# AngularJS directve link scope in ng-repeat on template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this directive:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('hrefDirective',['productosService']);

    app.directive('customHref', ['productosService', function(productosService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<li ng-repeat="familia in getfamilias"><p><a ng-bind="familia.name" ng-href="{{familia.href}}"></a></p></li>',           
            link : function(scope, element, attrs){
                productosService.getFamilias().then(function(data){
                    scope.getfamilias = data.data;
                    for(var t in scope.getfamilias){
                        productosService.getFinalFamilias(scope.getfamilias[t].id).then(function(result){
                            scope.getfamilias[t].href = result.data.rows == 0 ? '#/producto' : '#/productos/{{familia.name}}';
                        });
                    }                               
                });
            }
        };
    }]);    
})();
```

I´m not being able to render the ng-bind inside the template. the scope.getfamilias inside the link has this structure:

```
{id: "x", name: "xxxx", id_categoria: "x"}
```

In the link I'm getting the original getfamilias object through a service and using the id property in a new service to get a new propierty and pushing it to the original getfamilias object to use it as href inside the template, but it's not working.

Any clues about how I can get the value to the template?

Comment: Inside the service call then callback why dont you check what is `t` ?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my answer. I have made a plunkr and tried to mock your service's responses with fixed values. It is working in there :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code so I'll suggest you to use the following:

```
 app.directive('customHref', ['productosService', function(productosService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<li ng-repeat="familia in getfamilias"><p><a ng-bind="familia.name" ng-href="{{familia.href}}"></a></p></li>',           
            link : function(scope, element, attrs){
                productosService.getFamilias().then(function(data){
                    // you have to make sure your data.data has a collection, I don't know your complete code, 
                    // so I'm just leaving this part as it is. 
                    scope.getfamilias = data.data;

                    //Use angular.forEach instead of for(x in y)
                    angular.forEach(scope.getfamilias, function(familia){
                        productosService.getFinalFamilias(familia.id).then(function(result){

                            // render the name here instead of using '#/productos/{{familia.name}}'
                            familia.href = result.data.rows === 0 ? '#/producto' : '#/productos/' + familia.name ;
                        });
                    });                              
                });

            }
        };
    }]);
```

I have made a plunkr for you, please have a look:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FBS257ddJKTdYGVP4d7Y?p=catalogue

Comment: Nice answer, probably you can mention what actually happens in OPs case just so OP understands. +1 for the extra effort.